Kotlin - Exposed. How to run multiple tasks concurrently on the same transaction with exposed?
I'm trying to make some work run concurrently to speed up the process.
Instead of running a batch job synchronously i want to run individual tasks with 10 threads/coroutines.
I want to process this all on a single transaction. If 1 job failed, the entire batch should be rollbacked.
Unfortunately, the code that i'm calling contains a lot of the following blocks. Also in code that i cannot change:
transaction {
}

These are several layers deep and i cannot change that.
Under the hood this seems to use a ThreadLocalTransactionManager. This means if threads are switched, a new transaction was created, and partial work was committed.
I tried using
(TransactionManager.manager as ThreadLocalTransactionManager).bindTransactionToThread(transaction)

However, this in turns creates a range of problems:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't finish initialization for entity xxxDao - the initialization order is broken
at org.jetbrains.exposed.dao.EntityCache.finishEntityInitialization$exposed_dao(EntityCache.kt:84)
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: null
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientException: The object is already closed [90007-214]
Maybe it's best to illustrate my intentions with the following (pseudo) code, that does not work:
    val semaphore = Semaphore(10)  // Limit to 10 concurrent coroutines

    transaction {
        val transaction = this
        try {
            val deferredProcessedRows: List<Deferred<RowResult>> = nonEmptyRows.mapIndexed { rowIndex, row ->
                scope.async {
                    (TransactionManager.manager as ThreadLocalTransactionManager).bindTransactionToThread(transaction)
                    log.info("processing task on transaction with ${transaction.id}")
                    semaphore.withPermit {
                        return@async doTask(..) // returns object or error
                    }
                }
            }
            processedRows = runBlocking {
                deferredProcessedRows.awaitAll()
            }

            val hasErrors = processedRows.any { it.error != null }
            if (hasErrors) {
                rollback()
            }
            // Only commit if all operations succeed
            commit()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            // Rollback if any operation fails
            rollback()
        }
    }

How should i fix this? or how should i implement this?

a batchjob consisting of tasks.
handle 10 tasks concurrently
in case of 1 failure, rollback everything.
code i'm calling already contains a lot of transaction-blocks

